# Promise based queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an array of `files`, that I'd like to attack `N` at a time. And a function `doWork` that returns a promise.

```
var files = []

var doWork = function(file) {
  return asyncFn(file)
}
```

I'd like to be able to push onto this queue dynamically.

**Edit**: I've tried various modules (promise-queue, async-q). They all work in a fashion, but they don't allow using an array as a queue. They have there own internal structure that you need to push onto.

The reason I need to use an array as I want to be able to push an item onto the queue, and check that it's not already on the queue.

Comment: Please put a question in your question.  What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you use Bluebird it has this built in (with an array) would an answer that does this interest you

Comment: I am using Bluebird, but I couldn't see a method that helped me. Curious.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra adding an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do that with Bluebird which you indicated you were using.

```
var files = ["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.txt"];
var task = Promise.map(files, doWork, {concurrency: 4}); // four at a time 

task.then(function(results){
       // results contains the results, tasks are executed at most 4 at a time
});
```

A word of caution - this puts an *upper limit* on how much the *current invocation* will run, calling the function multiple times, or from multiple node processes will (obviously) execute with larger/smaller concurrency. However in the simple case - this works.

Comment: This does not look like a queue to me - with `{concurrency: 1}` it might be. And it doesn't seem to be dynamic (I'd assume the OP means with this that you could still add tasks while the queue is already running)?

Comment: @Bergi the first line is: "I have an array of files, that I'd like to attack N at a time. And a function doWork that returns a promise.". It's not dynamic, but it's definitely a queue.

Comment: You're right - have an upvote from me :-). @Dominic: If you're looking for a solution that lets you push onto the queue while it's already running, let us know (I'll make an answer)

Comment: Hi Bergi. I was not familiar with the concurrency para for map, thanks. I would like a dynamic queue. I've edited my question to include the current way I have accomplished this.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra me and Bergi are two different people :P Also, you haven't updated the question from what I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
function enq (step)
  var f = function() {
    var d = Q.defer();
    step(d);
    return d.promise;
  }
  enq_head = enq_head.then(f);
}
```

where step is a function that fulfills the promise you pass it. But I don't recommend it cos it's just a fancy way of doing what setTimeout does much more efficiently.

If you want to keep track of which files you've scheduled and/or completed, just put them in a done list or take them out of the todo list you get them from, stick a bool in an object under the filename or whatever. It's a seperate problem from the scheduling.